# SVG cuts off certain Word

Tags: html, svg

I have a problem. I have a SVG and in this SVG "`Does`" is cut off. How can I make it display so that the whole word is displayed?

In addition
`Does not arrive next day` should only go up to the dash with some spacing and `Arrvies next day` should start at the dash

[image]

```html
<svg style="margin-left: 50px;width: 500px;height: 310px;">
<text x="87.5" y="15" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);">Does not arrive next day</text><text x="262.5" y="15" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);">Arrives next day</text><text x="173" y="36" text-anchor="end" font-size="14">occur_last_6_months &lt;...</text>
  <rect height="10" x="145.42239460557676" y="39" width="29.57760539442325" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></rect><text x="144.42239460557676" text-anchor="end" y="49" font-size="10">0.20</text><text x="173" y="65" text-anchor="end" font-size="14">lastindays &gt; 5.00</text>
  <rect height="10" x="157.68897203461782" y="68" width="17.311027965382177" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></rect><text x="156.68897203461782" text-anchor="end" y="78" font-size="10">0.12</text><text x="177" y="94" text-anchor="begin" font-size="14">isDangerousGoods &lt;=...</text>
  <rect height="10" x="175" y="97" width="1.6878657887743784" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);"></rect><text x="177.6878657887744" text-anchor="begin" y="107" font-size="10">0.01</text><text x="177" y="123" text-anchor="begin" font-size="14">rfmScore &lt;= 5.00</text>
  <rect height="10" x="175" y="126" width="1.6275210348426128" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);"></rect><text x="177.6275210348426" text-anchor="begin" y="136" font-size="10">0.01</text><text x="173" y="152" text-anchor="end" font-size="14">16.00 &lt; orderDate_day...</text>
  <rect height="10" x="173.74463261909614" y="155" width="1.2553673809038697" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></rect><text x="172.74463261909614" text-anchor="end" y="165" font-size="10">0.01</text><text x="173" y="181" text-anchor="end" font-size="14">2021.00 &lt; confirmedD...</text>
  <rect height="10" x="173.8225265660096" y="184" width="1.1774734339904038" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></rect><text x="172.8225265660096" text-anchor="end" y="194" font-size="10">0.01</text><text x="177" y="210" text-anchor="begin" font-size="14">netPrice &lt;= 648.40</text>
  <rect height="10" x="175" y="213" width="0.8320837499799663" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);"></rect><text x="176.83208374997997" text-anchor="begin" y="223" font-size="10">0.01</text><text x="177" y="239" text-anchor="begin" font-size="14">16.00 &lt; day_isArrive...</text>
  <rect height="10" x="175" y="242" width="0.8185508135712415" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);"></rect><text x="176.81855081357125" text-anchor="begin" y="252" font-size="10">0.01</text><text x="177" y="268" text-anchor="begin" font-size="14">isArrivedAtHub_timest...</text>
  <rect height="10" x="175" y="271" width="0.8149906729038177" style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);"></rect><text x="176.8149906729038" text-anchor="begin" y="281" font-size="10">0.01</text><text x="173" y="297" text-anchor="end" font-size="14">dimensions_length &lt;= ...</text>
  <rect height="10" x="174.2591805995315" y="300" width="0.7408194004684877" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></rect><text x="173.2591805995315" text-anchor="end" y="310" font-size="10">0.01</text>
  <line x1="175" x2="175" y1="30" y2="310" style="stroke-width: 2; stroke: black;"></line>
</svg>
```

What I want

[image]

Comment: For _Arrives next day_ use `text-anchor="start"`  For _Does not arrive next day_ use `text-anchor="end"`  Set the x of the text at the vertical line. Also change the size of the text to something smaller

Comment: Apparently, the current layout is specific to font settings. In other words: the layout looks messed up due to hardcoded positioning (e.g. Robot Condensed - perfect; Arial - meh!).  If you have control of the data driven output, please add more details. If your svg is static and given – you need to unravel the text alignment and positioning. E.g.  adjust the text starting points and alignment properties `text-anchor`. Currently both seem to be set quite arbitrarily. Quick and dirty "fix":  apply a `overflow:visible` to your `<svg>` element (won't  solve aligment issues, but no cropping).